# I am unable to solve this error

Tags: package-management, dependencies

```
$ sudo apt install rabbitmq-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rabbitmq-server : Depends: erlang-base (>= 1:25.0) but 1:24.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed or
                            erlang-base-hipe (>= 1:25.0) but it is not installable or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:25.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-crypto (>= 1:25.0) but 1:24.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:25.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-eldap (>= 1:25.0) but 1:24.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:25.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-inets (>= 1:25.0) but 1:24.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:25.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-mnesia (>= 1:25.0) but 1:24.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:25.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-os-mon (>= 1:25.0) but 1:24.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:25.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-parsetools (>= 1:25.0) but 1:24.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:25.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-public-key (>= 1:25.0) but 1:24.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:25.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-runtime-tools (>= 1:25.0) but 1:24.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:25.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-ssl (>= 1:25.0) but 1:24.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:25.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-syntax-tools (>= 1:25.0) but 1:24.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:25.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-tools (>= 1:25.0) but 1:24.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:25.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-xmerl (>= 1:25.0) but 1:24.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:25.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; I picked one line (*from your pasted message*) & looked up results & do note a Ubuntu product/release that meets that requirement, but you haven't provided your details thus I can't provide more... As you know what OS/release you're using, and we're limited to what you provide - you'll have to explore yourself currently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: The output strongly suggests that you are attempting to install rabbitmq-server from some non-Ubuntu source instead of installing from the Ubuntu repositories. The package in the Ubuntu repositories is compatible; your non-Ubuntu package is incompatible.